# Compute differential of Even function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, If $f$ is a differentiable function and $f(-\vec{x})=f(\vec{x}) ,\forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

Compute the differential of $f$ in $\vec{0}$.

I don't know how to tackle this question.

Comment: Well, I do know that if $df(\vec{0})$ is de differential of $f$ in $\vec{0}$ then, $df(\vec{0})=\nabla f(\vec{0})\vec{h}$, because the differentiability of f implies all partial derivatives exists.

Comment: Then try to show that $\nabla f(\vec0) = \vec0$ if $f$ is even and differentiable at $\vec0$.

Comment: Yes! But don't know how to tackle this idea. Could you be more explicit?@AlexR

Comment: Show for $n=1$ and induce for arbitrary $n$. For the $n=1$ case think about what _difference quotient_ you should look at (i.e. what approximation of $f'$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Prop. 1**
>   If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0+x) = f(x_0-x) \ \forall\ x\in\mathbb R$ then $f'(x_0) = 0$

*Proof:* We use that $f'(x_0)$ exists to write it as
$$\begin{align*}
f'(x_0) &= \frac12 \left( \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_o)}h + \lim_{j\to0} \frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-j)}j \right) \\
& = \lim_{h\to0} \frac12 \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0+h)}h = \frac12 \lim_{h\to0} \frac0h = 0
\end{align*}$$

> **Prop. 2**
>   If $f:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0+x) = f(x_0-x)\ \forall\ x\in\mathbb R^n$ then $\nabla f(x_0) = \vec0$

*Proof*: We use Prop. 1 on the functions $f_j(t) := f(x_0 + te_j)$. Then $(\nabla f(x_0))_j = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f_j(0) = 0$ because $f_j$ are even: $f_j(t) = f(x_0 + te_j) = f(x_0 - te_j) = f_j(-t)$